# Access Multiple Folders Located in SharePoint Document Library and Display its Content on Webpage

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I can access a single folder located inside a SharePoint Document Library and display its content on a webpage.  I’m able to access the second (different) folder inside the same SharePoint Document Library and display its content.  The only way I figured out how to accomplish this is by duplicating the script and placing the scripts inside their own separate function.  I invoke one of the functions by the way of a callback function.  Below is the script showing what I am doing.

The process I’m using do what I’m wishing to achieve with spotty results, sometimes in works; meaning sometimes one of the folders contents will display and sometimes both folders content will display, it’s hit or miss.  Is there a better way I can accomplish this and received a consistent result; consistently display both folders content on the webpage.  Any help will be appreciated.

Script I"m using:

```
 memoColumn(regColumn);

//Left Column List
function memoColumn(regulations) {
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
  $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", function() {
   $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function() {
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.DocumentManagement.js", createDocumentSet);
   });
  });
 });
 var docSetFiles;

 function createDocumentSet() {
  //Get the client context,web and library object.   
  clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
  var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("Legacy_DSS_Files");
  clientContext.load(oList);
  //Get the root folder of the library   
  oLibraryFolder = oList.get_rootFolder();
  var documentSetFolder = "/sites/dcsa/ep/Legacy_DSS/Memos";
  //Get the document set files using CAML query   
  var camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
  camlQuery.set_folderServerRelativeUrl(documentSetFolder);
  docSetFiles = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
  //Load the client context and execute the batch   
  clientContext.load(docSetFiles, 'Include(File)');
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess, QueryFailure);
 }

 function QuerySuccess() {

  var csv = 'Document Name, URL Name, Created Date, Modified Date\n';

  var docSetFilesEnumerator = docSetFiles.getEnumerator();
  while (docSetFilesEnumerator.moveNext()) {
   var oDoc = docSetFilesEnumerator.get_current().get_file();

   csv += oDoc.get_name() + ',' + 'https://intelshare.intelink.gov' + oDoc.get_serverRelativeUrl() + ',' + oDoc.get_timeCreated() + ',' + oDoc.get_timeLastModified(); //if more cloumns
   csv += "\n";

   var link = document.getElementById("prvMinutes1");

   link.innerHTML += '<li class="linkData" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><a href="' + 'https://intelshare.intelink.gov' + oDoc2.get_serverRelativeUrl() + '" target="_blank">' + oDoc2.get_name().replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + '</a></li><br>';

  }
 }


 function QueryFailure() {
  console.log('Request failed - ' + args.get_message());
 }

 regulations();
} ///End of Memo Column Function


//Right Column List
function regColumn() {
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
  $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", function() {
   $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function() {
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.DocumentManagement.js", createDocumentSet);
   });
  });
 });
 var docSetFiles;

 function createDocumentSet() {
  //Get the client context,web and library object.   
  clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
  var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("Legacy_DSS_Files");
  clientContext.load(oList);
  //Get the root folder of the library   
  oLibraryFolder = oList.get_rootFolder();
  var documentSetFolder = "/sites/dcsa/ep/Legacy_DSS/Regulations";
  //Get the document set files using CAML query   
  var camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
  camlQuery.set_folderServerRelativeUrl(documentSetFolder);
  docSetFiles = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
  //Load the client context and execute the batch   
  clientContext.load(docSetFiles, 'Include(File)');
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess, QueryFailure);
 }

 function QuerySuccess() {

  var csv = 'Document Name, URL Name, Created Date, Modified Date\n';

  var docSetFilesEnumerator = docSetFiles.getEnumerator();
  while (docSetFilesEnumerator.moveNext()) {
   var oDoc2 = docSetFilesEnumerator.get_current().get_file();

   csv += oDoc2.get_name() + ',' + 'https://intelshare.intelink.gov' + oDoc2.get_serverRelativeUrl() + ',' + oDoc2.get_timeCreated() + ',' + oDoc2.get_timeLastModified(); //if more cloumns
   csv += "\n";

   var link2 = document.getElementById("prvMinutes2");

   link2.innerHTML += '<li class="linkData" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><a href="' + 'https://intelshare.intelink.gov' + oDoc2.get_serverRelativeUrl() + '" target="_blank">' + oDoc2.get_name().replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + '</a></li><br>';

  }


 }

 function QueryFailure() {
  console.log('Request failed - ' + args.get_message());
 }

} ///End of Regulations Columns Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use REST API to achieve it. The following code for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    getFilesFromFolder("/sites/dcsa/ep/Legacy_DSS/Memos").done(function(data){
        $.each(data.d.results,function(i,item){
            $("#prvMinutes1").append('<li class="linkData" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><a href="' + 'https://intelshare.intelink.gov' + item.ServerRelativeUrl + '" target="_blank">' + item.Name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + '</a></li><br>');
        });
    });
    getFilesFromFolder("/sites/dcsa/ep/Legacy_DSS/Regulations").done(function(data){
        $.each(data.d.results,function(i,item){
            $("#prvMinutes2").append('<li class="linkData" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><a href="' + 'https://intelshare.intelink.gov' + item.ServerRelativeUrl + '" target="_blank">' + item.Name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + '</a></li><br>');
        });
    });
})
function getFilesFromFolder(serverRelativeUrlToFolder){
    return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('"+serverRelativeUrlToFolder+"')/files",
        method: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
    });
}
</script>

<div>
<ul id="prvMinutes1"></ul>
<ul id="prvMinutes2"></ul>
</div>
```

**Reference**: [Working with folders and files with REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-by-using-rest)

Comment: Awesome!!!! Works like a charm!  Nice and clean and very simple to expand with a new folder additions.  Also thank you for the resource.  I love to read up on how things work and to add new guidance to my technical library.  Thank you!